# how to make dynamic structural directive based upon host element

Tags: angular

Our organization is migrating from AngularJS to Angular.  In the angular world, we had an attirbute directive that we used for making an input render as just text if we were in "read-only" mode.

Assuming `myfield` is "my value", then

```
<input my-readonly="true" type="text ng-model="myfield"></input>
```

would render just

```
my value
```

instead of the input element.

In addition, it was smart enough to apply specific formatting based upon the type input type.  So date, number, text, and tel would all be formatted to our style.

I'm trying to duplicate this functionality in Angular, but not making any head way.  Ideally, it would work as follows

```
<input *myReadonly="true" type="text ng-model="myfield"></input>
```

Initially, I tried setting my selector to `input[type=text][myReadonly]` however, with the way the templates expand, the DOM (or AST) never actually looks like that.  Second, I looked through the API to see if there is anyway to look at the host before deciding to render it, but the `TemplateRef` doesn't seem to have any reflective properties on it.

Lastly, if there is a way to dynamically figure out which way to render, I also need access to the current value, ie `ngModel`.  So, this might not work for us at all.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: Is your directive applied only to input type=text?

Comment: No. Any input, text, number, tel.  That is the tricky bit.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody is answering I will try. Looks very hacky.

1. Create a dircetive that accepts NgModel in constructor
2. Add the the directive that your put on input.
3. Create a DOM element with static text for readOnly.
4. After that replace old dom with new one. this.el.nativeElement.parentElement.replaceChild(this.el.nativeElement, newDOM);